# Youtube embedded video produces error "ytcfg is not defined"

Tags: javascript, youtube

The following erro message appears in the browser console if there is embedding youtube video on the page:

[image]

Note: no API was used for embedding, e.g. Youtube iFrame API - just a raw iframe.

It is also reproducible on the youtube website if you go to some video, click the Share button and choose the Embed tab. Or just open some video link in a new browser window, like https://www.youtube.com/embed/.....

Is there something I can do about this error message?

Comment: Just got this as well. maybe they changed some part of their api. haven't been having these issues in the past

Comment: I just started seeing the same problem, no code change on my side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: ytcfg is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622204/uncaught-referenceerror-ytcfg-is-not-defined)

Comment: you are partially right @PeterO. It is similar question, but mine was asked 3 hours before...

Answer (score 1):

Its broken on their own site too

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo