# Uncaught ReferenceError: ytcfg is not defined even though I won't use that as I am using yt player

Tags: angularjs, cordova, youtube-api, desktop-application, ytplayer

I have been using the YouTube IFrame Player API without problem for months and started to see this exception recently when the player loads:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ytcfg is not defined when I see the console.

Also by this error my app crashes.

This question is already asked in [Uncaught ReferenceError: ytcfg is not defined (also __ytRIL is not defined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622204/uncaught-referenceerror-ytcfg-is-not-defined) - but there is not mention with that issue the site/app crashes.

The worth noting about that the same code worked properly on Android OS(app developed using cordova) but on the Other OS the app crashes.

How can I prevent this from crashing my app?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you switched [according to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40652827/870729)?

Comment: They are saying youtube API error it is. So I am unable to configure out what the problem was. Atleast app should not be crash by that problem

Answer (score 7):

This is a Google API bug. You can see the bug confirmed here:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=8668

Comment: Please go and vote for the bug to get fixed. they are sitting on it for more than 1 month.

Comment: I think Google API bug fixes as youtube video is now playing