# tracking embed video events with Youtube API - ytcfg is not defined(…)

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, youtube-api, embed

I found this [tutorial](https://megalytic.com/blog/tracking-youtube-videos-using-google-analytics) on how to track GA events of embed youtube videos and did my script by it:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  });

  // This code is called by the YouTube API to create the player object
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(event) {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  var done = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

    // track when user clicks to Play
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && done===false) {
      ga('send', 'event', 'Video', 'Prehratie videa', 'GE', 1);
      done = true;
    }
  }

}(jQuery));
```

The script is added at every page in theme_preprocess_page(). However, I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ytcfg is not defined(…)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622204/uncaught-referenceerror-ytcfg-is-not-defined) you can read it is an error at youtube's side. It is true that everything is ok in my script and is there something I could do in order to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is a bug on the YouTube part and there is now an [existing bug ticket](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8745) for this. You can always check this bug ticket for an update on this issue.

For the workaround, I found in this [YouTube Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/3Z7dSnwkCH4) to use objects instead of iframes. You can try this temporary solution if it works in your case. Hope it helps you.